# Is there a more performant alternative to $watch in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-scope, watch

We have a huge enterprise Angular application we are having performance issues, sometimes it kills the browser(out of memory). We debug the app using browser developer profiler (*DevTools*), and it takes lot of time on `$apply()` function.

I did some research and it looks like `$apply()` is fired every time angular runs the digest cycle.

I noticed a significant amount of `$watch()` in controllers. The architecture is entirely based on `$watch()` (it is a kind of subscribe/observe pattern). Because of that, we have no other option but `$watch()`. I am not allowed to publish any code of this application.

So, my question is, is there a more performant alternative to watch data structures, so the performance of the application can be improved?

Comment: You are correct in saying that `$watch` and digest cycles are very expensive in Angular. There are many ways we can make that logic more performant but it really depends on your particular architecture and logic. This question is very broad, try to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an specific example of code will be hard to determine where your performance  problem is.
However the answer to your question is yes. as a matter of fact, I wrote an article about it, no long:  [optimizing-code-object-defineproperty-scope-watch-angularjs](http://www.jomendez.com/2015/02/25/optimizing-code-object-defineproperty-scope-watch-angularjs/)

You can achieve the same functionality of a watch more efficiently with Object.defineProperty() (see code example below)
Note: this solution is not supported by IE8 and below.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
myApp.service('efficientWatch', efficientWatch);


MyCtrl.$inject = ['efficientWatch'];

function MyCtrl(efficientWatch) {
    var self = this;
    efficientWatch.watch('reactionText', self, function (newval) {
        if (newval == 'watched') {
            self.reacted = true;
        }else{
            self.reacted = false;
        };
    });
    self.reacted = false;
    self.placeholder = 'type the watched word';
}

function efficientWatch() {
    this.watch = function (name, controllerProto, func) {
        Object.defineProperty(controllerProto,
        name, {
            get: function () {
                return this._personName;
            },
            set: function (newValue) {
                this._personName = newValue;

                //Call method on update
                if (typeof func == 'function') func(newValue);
            },
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    };
};
```

Hope this was help you ;)